# JQuery Autocomplete Combobox: MVC3 Validation not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, validation, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use [JQuery UI Autocomplete (Combobox)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) with a dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC3.

Here is the relevant section of code in my view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MerchantID, "Merchant")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("MerchantID", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "combobox" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MerchantID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FinancialAccountID, "FinancialAccount")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("FinancialAccountID", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "combobox" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FinancialAccountID)
    </div>
```

(there's anywhere from 4-10 dropdown lists.)

Here is the contents of the javascript file, essentially copied from the [jquery-ui website](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox):

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.combobox", {
        _create: function () {
            var input,
                    self = this,
                    select = this.element.hide(),
                    selected = select.children(":selected"),
                    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
                    wrapper = this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                        .addClass("ui-combobox")
                        .insertAfter(select);

            input = $("<input>")
                    .appendTo(wrapper)
                    .val(value)
                    .addClass("ui-state-default ui-combobox-input")
                    .autocomplete({
                        delay: 0,
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                            response(select.children("option").map(function () {
                                var text = $(this).text();
                                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                    return {
                                        label: text.replace(
                                            new RegExp(
                                                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                            ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                        value: text,
                                        option: this
                                    };
                            }));
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            self._trigger("selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
                        change: function (event, ui) {
                            if (!ui.item) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                                    valid = false;
                                select.children("option").each(function () {
                                    if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                if (!valid) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    $(this).val("");
                                    select.val("");
                                    input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

            input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                        .appendTo(ul);
            };

            $("<a>")
                    .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                    .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                    .appendTo(wrapper)
                    .button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text: false
                    })
                    .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle")
                    .click(function () {
                        // close if already visible
                        if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                            input.autocomplete("close");
                            return;
                        }

                        // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                        $(this).blur();

                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete("search", "");
                        input.focus();
                    });
        },

        destroy: function () {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    $(".combobox").combobox();
});
```

The problem I'm having is that there doesn't seem to be any validation done on the values entered.  For example, if I leave it blank and submit, there's no error indicating that invalid information has been entered.  However, if I comment out the combobox() call to disable the combobox functionality, validation works properly.

I have done some searching on stackoverflow for this issue, but I can't seem to find anything that matches this specific situation.

Edit:  I have discovered that validation actually does happen, but only if I click another field before submitting, which is odd.   So if I enter blank text into a combobox, then click into a text field, then submit, it works properly (shows validation errors.) But if I enter blank text into the combobox and submit, it doesn't show validation errors. Any ideas?

Comment: The only difference I see between your code and the jquery example is that you are applying the combobox function by class as opposed to ID.  Have you tried only applying it to a single element by ID first?

Comment: @Shawn Thank you for your reply.  I tried your suggestion, but the behavior unfortunately didn't change.  However, I did observe more details about the problem, which I added to my post.  I discovered that validation actually does happen, but only if I click another field before submitting, which is odd. So if I enter blank text into a combobox, then click into a text field, then submit, it works properly (shows validation errors.) But if I enter blank text into the combobox and submit, it doesn't show validation errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem.

When the submit button was pressed, the javascript validation was called *before* the Autocomplete JQuery that cleared the selected item when bad input was detected.  This is the part I mean:

```
if (!valid) {
     // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
     $(this).val("");
     select.val("");
     input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
     return false;
}
```

So I made it clear the selected item as soon as the user starts typing and only reselect when a valid item is selected.

```
source: function (request, response) {
    select.val(""); //as soon as typing is started, the select input is cleared.  This makes sure validation always occurs
    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response(select.children("option").map(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
            return {
                label: text.replace(
                    new RegExp(
                        "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                        $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                        ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                    ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                value: text,
                option: this
            };
    }));
},
```

Comment: That is helpful, where do you include these 2 functions?

Comment: @learning My original question showed the full javascript code, which needs to be included on the page in some way (through a bundle, probably.)  My answer just changes part of that code (the source parameter of autocomplete.) Also, just as a warning, I haven't tested this on newer versions of jQuery, jQuery UI, or ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: The solution I used is in the link below. I do like the input clearing right away, I added this to my combobox +1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516841/how-to-get-unobtrusive-validation-on-my-jqueryui-element-combobox